# Sybase # tables

Tags: sybase, sap-ase

I am trying to debug a stored procedure(lets say proc1) that populates a #table, lets say #reserves. The procedure has no insert statements for #reserves but still there is some data being populated into the table which is being sent to the output as a result set.

Proc1 internally calls Proc2 which as well has a #reserves declared and is populated with some data. My question is - is there a way that Proc2.#reserves would send data to Proc1.#reserves?

Below is the sample procedure

```
Create Proc1
As
Begin

Create Table #Reserves
(
id int not null,
value int not null
)

Exec Proc2

Select id,
value 
from #Reserves
End

Create Proc2
AS
Begin

Create Table #Reserves
(
id int not null,
value int not null
)

Insert into #reserves
(id, value)
Select 1 as id,2 as value

End
```

Answer (score 1):

Each proc is creating it's own version of `#Reserves` (this is doable in ASE; if, before you exit `proc2`, you query your tempdb's `sysobjects` table you should see 2 entries for `name like '#Reserves%'`).

If you want `proc2` to populate the `#Reserves` created by `proc1`, consider modifying `proc2` to only create `#Reserves` if it doesn't already exist.